# How to create standalone python interpreter .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone please help to explain how we can create a standalone python interpreter (single file like py_interpreter.exe) with all the package installed in the pc.

Background of story:
I need to run my program (scripts.pyc) on a pc where python is not installed. So I want to run my .pyc file using the portable py_interpreter.exe.

I will use the batch script to run .pyc script.
@echo off
cls

set CWD_PATH=%~dp0

"%CWD_PATH%\py_interpreter.exe" "%CWD_PATH%\scripts.pyc"

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 pause

Sorry if my question is really stupid

Comment: I would recommend just sending them a link to install python.

Comment: Hi Flow, thanks for your response but it is not possible to install any external software in that PC. is there any other possible way to create executable of python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) project.

If you do not need console to be shown while running the produced binary,

```
pyinstaller  --noconsole --onefile src\script.py
```

if you need the console to be shown, just remove the --noconsole option. The executable would be created under the dist folder if everything goes well.

Comment: Hi Brijin, thanks for your response but my purpose is to make standalone executable of python interpreter not my script so i can use same standalone interpreter for other python scripts as well

Comment: @Priyanshu, you should checkout https://winpython.sourceforge.net/ then. It is portable, I think you can copy paste it into target machine and it should work.

Comment: I gone through https://winpython.sourceforge.net/ but it is not that convenient. I actually want to achieve exactly the same as it shared at https://www.orbitals.com/programs/pyexe.html but I want to do it for python3